# How to Select an Input Radio Button with a Specific CSS Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, frontend

I'm attempting to select an input radio button under a .show class in my HTML using JavaScript. Here's the HTML structure:

html:

```
<div class="collapse question-group show">
  <div class="progress">...</div>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio">
      <label>yes</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to include the .show class in the CSS selector because there are other similar div groups, and the only difference is the presence of the .show class. Without it, the element will be hidden.

I've tried using the following JavaScript code:

```
<script>
  var inputButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.show .form-check input[type="radio"]');
  inputButtons.forEach(input => {
    if (input.checked) {
      alert('hello!');
    }
  })
</script>
```

However, the alert window did not pop out, and it seems that the selection failed.

If I change the CSS path to:

```
var inputButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check input[type="radio"]');
```

It works as expected.

Is there any way to include the .show class in the CSS selector to select the desired input radio button?

Comment: You need to use `querySelectorAll()` with `forEach()`. Also, change the way you check for checked radio buttons. [That's what you want to do?](https://jsfiddle.net/mfcbv463/)

Comment: I see that you have changed to `querySelectorAll()`, doesn't it work as per my JSFiddle? I wanted to write an answer.

Comment: @SallylovesLightning thank you so much my friend ,it does not work as your per JSFiddle,I'm thinking about using javascript to detect visible element instead

Comment: Not sure, but my JSFiddle fires when the radio button is checked? What do you want instead?

Comment: I see class `progress` and class `question`... It looks like a survey. -- Are the questions dynamically added based on the "progress"?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes exactly ,it is a survey app ,and the questions are dynamically added based on the progress !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the questions are dynamically added based on the progress !

Then try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.question-group')
  .forEach((showEl) => {
    showEl.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      const target = event.target
      if(target.closest('.question-group')?.classList.contains('show') &&
        target.tagName === 'INPUT' &&
        target.type === 'radio' &&
        target.checked){
        alert('Hello')
      }
    })
  })
```

So the event handler is tied to the **static** `.question-group` elements... Then whenever a click event occurs on one of their childrens (be it dynamically created or not), the event will fire because it is tied to a still existing element of the DOM when the event handler was attached (most likely on page load).

The trick is about filtering on the childrens you want to interact with.

**For more**: That concept is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ,but still not work, seems the issue comes from the .show ,I replaced it with .collapse .question-group or .question ,any of them works ,but the .show not works...

Comment: I see... the `show` class is not the right reference to attach the event handlers on page load. I will edit.

Comment: Done. So now the event handler is tied to all elements with `question-group` class (which should not toggle). Then on event, we check if there is a parent (of the triggering element) with class `question-group` that also has the `show` class... Rest is the same.

Comment: Thank you so much again ,but this time ,even if I replace the .show with .collapse,it still not work,I'm checking is there any issue in your latest answer

Comment: Yes... check it now, I had a `const` misplaced during the edit process... should be good now.

Comment: Hi friend ,may I ask what if the logic change to ,all the radio buttons under .show need to be checked ,before alert('Hello') ?Because I have some questions group ,there are several questions together ,I need wait for every radio buttons have been checked ,then alert('hello')

Comment: Hi friend can you help answer this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76789612/trigger-javascript-function-when-all-radio-buttons-under-dynamically-added-class