# Trigger JavaScript function when all radio buttons under dynamically added class are checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a working code logic that triggers the `alert('hello')` function when a radio button, under a dynamically added class `.show`, is checked. Here's the current code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="collapse question-group show">
  <div class="progress">...</div>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" />
      <label>yes</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".question-group").forEach((showEl) => {
  showEl.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    if (
      target.closest(".question-group")?.classList.contains("show") &&
      target.tagName === "INPUT" &&
      target.type === "radio" &&
      target.checked
    ) {
      alert("Hello");
    }
  });
});
```

The current code works as expected. However, I have added more radio buttons under the `.show` class:

HTML:

```html
<div class="collapse question-group show">
  <div class="progress">...</div>

  <div class="question">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" />
      <label>yes1</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" />
      <label>yes2</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" />
      <label>yes3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to modify the current code to ensure that the `alert('hello')` function is triggered only when all the radio buttons under the `.show .question` class have been checked. If any radio button remains unchecked, the alert should not be triggered. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I tried, but it does not work; the alert window did not pop up:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".question-group").forEach((showEl) => {
  const allRadios = showEl.querySelectorAll('.form-check input[type="radio"]');
  let allChecked = false;

  showEl.addEventListener("change", () => {
    allChecked = Array.from(allRadios).every((radio) => radio.checked);
    if (allChecked) {
      alert("Hello");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You have included the `jquery` tag, but you have not used any jQuery in your code. Are you expecting a solution that uses jQuery?

Comment: What have you tried?  And at what point in your attempt did you not get the result you expected?  So far, you've given us your requirement but haven't told us anything about a problem or error.

Comment: @76484 sorry I have edit my question removed the jquery,please don't vote close my question

Comment: @devlincarnate I'm updating what I have tried ,thank you for your advise ,please don't close my question ,thanks

Comment: OK, that's closer.  Now edit your question and explain "did not work".  Did you get an error? No alert when you expected one?  Or what?

Comment: @devlincarnate yes done'but not work the alert window did not pop out'

Comment: Use `.every()` to test if something is true for all array elements. You'll need to convert the NodeList that `querySelectorAll()` returns to an array.

Comment: Your last example works for me in a Snippet. Is there something we're still missing?

Comment: You are indicating that the `show` class is added dynamically. Could you show how that is being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you invited me to anwer here, from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76775801/2159528)...

The only difference is you want to fire the `alert` if all the radios in a specific `.question-group` are checked.

So in this case, starting from the check event of a displayed radio, you have to get the relevant `.question-group` parent (which you already had from the previous answer).
Then from it, get all its child radios, instead of just using the current one.
If they're all checked, you have the winning condition you are looking for.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".question-group").forEach((showEl) => {
  showEl.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    const target = event.target
    const parentOfTarget = target.closest('.question-group')?.classList.contains('show')
    
    if(parentOfTarget &&
    target.tagName === 'INPUT' &&
    target.type === 'radio' &&
    target.checked){
      
      // Get all radio in that group
      const radios = parentOfTarget.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']")
      const allRadiosChecked = Array.from(radios).every((radio) => radio.checked)
      
      if(allRadiosChecked){
        alert("Hello");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am maintaining a counter which gets incremented/decremented within the event listener. Another approach might be to put the `querySelectorAll` statement within the event listener and use the `every` method.

```js
const radioButtons=[] 
document.querySelectorAll(
  '.question-group'
).forEach(d =>{
if(d.classList.contains('show')){
    radioButtons.push(...d.querySelectorAll('.question input[type="radio"]'));
}
});
console.log('radioButtons',radioButtons.length);
let checked = 0;
radioButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      checked++;
    } else {
      checked--;
    }

    if (checked === radioButtons.length) {
      alert("hello");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer ,however it does not work ,the alert window did not pop up.I think that is because the .show class is dynamically added ,that's why my first version JavaScript coded that way. I think you can't directly wrap the .show class with class .question-group

Comment: Edited the answer to use classList property to consider dynamically generated show class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,but it failed at this step:if(d.classList.contains('show')){
    radioButtons.push(...d.querySelectorAll('.question input[type="radio"]'));
} ,I add alert('yes') under this check ,the window did not pop out ,means ,it did not carputer the .show class

Answer (score 1):

You can have an event listener on the form (assuming that all radio buttons are in the same form) listening for `change`. You can then filter for the radio button that are not checked and if none is returned, display the alert. That is the first example.

In the second example I replaced the radio buttons with checkboxes. One could argue that checkboxes are better suited for this use case, because you can give the checkboxes the same name and select multiple. Whereas the radio buttons when having the same name, you can only select one at a time. So, the second example I use checkboxes.

#### Radio buttons:

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let notselected = [...form.elements]
    .filter(input => input.type == 'radio')
    .filter(input => input.checked == false);
  if(notselected.length == 0){
    alert('Hello');
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <div class="collapse question-group show">
    <div class="progress">...</div>

    <div class="question">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" />
        <label>yes1</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" />
        <label>yes2</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" />
        <label>yes3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Checkboxes:

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let notselected = [...form.elements.group1]
    .filter(input => input.checked == false);
  if(notselected.length == 0){
    alert('Hello');
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <div class="collapse question-group show">
    <div class="progress">...</div>

    <div class="question">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="group1" />
        <label>yes1</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="group1" />
        <label>yes2</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="group1" />
        <label>yes3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```